# Twig index type as string

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am grabbing the index of a for loop and passing it into a macro

```
{% for index, sectionForm in forms.sectionalCompletionTabForm.sections %}

    {{ macros.projectSectionForm(sectionForm, index) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am then wanting to count up with each index, ofcourse the index will start on 0 so I need to + 1 to whatever the index is.

```
{% macro projectSectionForm(form, index) %}

 {{ dump(index) }}
 {{ dump(index + 1) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

The problem is that index is coming back as a string eg. "1","2","3","4"

and whenever I + 1 to it i will always get 1 , possibly because it is adding a int and string?

I have looked on-line and I have not being able to find any kind of a toInt method.

My output looks like

"0" << index
 1 << index + 1
"1"<< index
1 << index + 1
"2"
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

If you don't need the index from the array, then you can use the `loop` variable.

`loop.index` and `look.index0` are 1 indexed, and 0 indexed respectively.

This variable is scoped to exist within the `for loop`.

Comment: Great Answer Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you should try the number_format filter

```
   {{ dump(index|number_format + 1) }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html